# Create custom java printing service attributes

Tags: java, service, printing

I need to create custom javax.print.attributes.Attribute and pass it to printer.

Java manual tells, how can I create my own attributes - that's realy easy. But my attributes will not be passed to printing service, until they are in getSupportedAttributeCategories() list.

How should I add my attribute category to getSupportedAttributeCategories()? Should I add something to printer's .ppd or write my own custom printer driver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I figured out, that actually **I can't add custom attribute category** in my case (JPS + Cups), because all attribute categories are already **hardcoded** in IPPPrintService class (the one, that communicates with Cups) and you can't add your own.

Still, you, of cause, can add custom attributes to existing 11 categories.